# Microsoft PKI + Samba AD

Tags: samba, pki

Have you ever tried to build Samba as Active directory domain controller in order to install Active Directory Certificate Services?

The purpose is to have an enterprise ca with samba ad instead of common microsoft active directory.

The only thing i didn't manage to fix is a smart card logon certificate in order user to login with theirs smart cards.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have a problem with `krb5.conf` in order to use a smart card!
Seems that the Samba AD does not recognize the rootca certificate and the domain certificate (private and public key) according to the following link:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_Smart_Card_Login

This article explains how to build the ca over samba but I have already one with Microsoft PKI  services.